# Is it because of no results return by array $result

Tags: php

I am getting error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line

```
$rows['id'] = $result['id'];
```

**Is it because of no results return by array $result?**

```
if ($tag == 'chins') {

        $clubId = $obj->club_id;
        if(isset($clubId))
        {
            $results = $db->club_chins($clubId);
        }else{
            $results = $db->chins();
        }

        if ($results != false) {
            // user found
            // echo json with success = 1

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $array = array();
            foreach($results as $result){
                $rows['id'] = $result['id'];
```

Comment: `Print_r($result)` make sure it is __array__.

Comment: `var_dump($results);` <- good place to start debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` *isn't* an array, it's an object (called `stdClass` in PHP).  You need to use the `->` to get properties.

```
$rows['id'] = $result->id;
```